# STATUS_BREAKPOINT chromium preventative measures

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, chromium

We are currently creating a SPA (JS Web-components, proprietary library, MQTT remote-binding, memory usage <50MB) and on some devices we regularly encounter the STATUS_BREAKPOINT Error (mostly) on chromium based User-Agents and bound to specific devices (observed more frequently on redraws, but often also seen on discarded tabs, having DevTools open also raised the frequency of the issue)
Online user-focused advice seems to indicate a plethora of potential causes and solutions, none of which are applicable to our systems.

The more important issue for us is of course ensuring that our users do not suffer similar issues
According to some google group the error code indicates a CPU breakpoint error.
To understand the issue and find potential solutions we can implement in our application I have this question:

How does one reduce the risk of browsers running into the STATUS_BREAKPOINT Error in complex SPAs? / What are potential code patterns that can cause this?

Comment: I am aware that this might be the wrong StackExchange, but believe this is the most likely one to produce an appropriate solution from the developer POV. If I am mistaken in this assumption, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

`STATUS_BREAKPOINT` occurring in production is likely an unintended Chromium bug or an unexpected state caused by your application that may or may not be supported by Chromium. You should file a bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/wizard with crash IDs from chrome://crashes so the Chromium team can investigate the cause.

You may also be able to investigate yourself if you enable logging in Chromium (https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282) and have some familiarity with the crash report format and Chromium source code.